# checked value inside change event IE 7-8 vs others

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Does anyone know why this code will print out true in FF, Chrome and IE9 and false in IE 7-8? And of course how to make it consistent.

```
$("#cb1").on("change", function(e) {
    $("#value").text(e.target.checked);
});

$("#cb1").trigger("click");
```

and the HTML is

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" />
<div id="value"></div>
```

I also prepared a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beradrian/WkGUr/8/).

Comment: try replacing `e` with `event` just for fun (jQuery should normalize it, I think) ?

Comment: Triggering the click programmatically won't trigger the change event

Comment: @adeneo It's a function parameter, what it is called shouldn't matter.

Comment: @KevinB - it's a pretty specific parameter, it's the `event`, and in IE it should work just by specifying `event`, and you don't need the `e` if I remember correctly ?

Comment: Same story :). It would have been crazy to work.

Comment: @wirey oh but it is triggering it though... very odd.

Comment: @KevinB Oh yeah.. it is :P

Comment: @adeneo What you remember is correct, but if you use attachEvent. In jquery - different thing.

Comment: @wirey Actually it does trigger it, even in IE 7-8. Only the .checked value is incorrect. And only in IE 7-8.

Comment: For some reason the first change event fires before the click, when the checked state is actually false. When adding a timeout it seems to work -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WkGUr/11/) ...

Comment: Yep, indeed with a timeout works. Actually if you get the .checked value after triggering click is also true. As I said, the event is triggered, only the .checked value inside is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is returning false in IE is due to the timing / ordering of events.

In IE when the change event is triggering, the checked attribute has not yet been set.

Once that event competes however it has been set and .checked will return true.

I don’t believe this is the best way to implement this but to answer your question...

Based on your existing code wrapping the actual setting the text in a setTimeout call will delay its execution.

This means when the code executes this change even will have completed, the checked attribute will be set and the "correct" / desired behaviour will be seen.

I have updated your fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/WkGUr/16/

```
$("#cb1").on("change", function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#value").text(e.target.checked);
    }, 0);
});

$("#cb1").trigger("click");
```

Comment: The problem is that after the last line (the one that triggers the `click` event) the text of `#value` element is not set.

Comment: Do you mean right after that line has run? The value will not be set untill the click event has been handeled, the change event triggered and then handeled and then the timeout has occured. Visualy this is fast and unseen but if you are on a breakpoint it will not happen.

Comment: I meant after line `$("#cb1").trigger("click");`. Visually yes, is fast enough, but if I have after some code that depends on that value ...